# Couldnt find the Error in Guess Game Class

Tags: java, class

Okay, this is part of the full code of a guessing game.

```
public static void Game(){              //Second page of game with option of continue playing when guessed close enough to answer.
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    GuessingGame testgame=new GuessingGame();

    testgame.Generator();
    int num = testgame.GetGenNum();
    //Produces a random number between 1 and 100 inclusive of 1 and 100


    System.out.println("Guess the target integer which is between 1 and 100 inclusive");

    int guess=scan.nextInt();

    int difference=(guess-num);



    while(guess!=num){
        int yesCounter=0;

        System.out.println("Guess again " +num+" "+difference);
        guess=scan.nextInt();
        difference=(guess-num);


        ///something wrong here, shouldnt repeat if difference too big 
        if(difference<=5||difference>=-5){  //something wrong with the condition, it says its close enough even tho it isnt.    
        while(yesCounter<1){
            System.out.println("Close enough, do you want to keep Guessing? Y/N ");
            yesCounter++;


            String play = scan.nextLine();
            //play=play1;
            while(!(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")))
            {


                if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                    System.exit(1);
                }

                else{
                    if((play.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))){
                        invalid();
                        guess=scan.nextInt();
                    }
                    else{
                        Game();             ///TAKE note as it might restart the game with new random integer
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }   

    }
```

output is:

.........................

Play? Y/N

y

Guess the target integer which is between 1 and 100 inclusive

50

Guess again 44 6

44

Close enough, do you want to keep Guessing? Y/N

Guess the target integer which is between 1 and 100 inclusive

..........................

the problem is, when user guess a number, the condition is if the difference between the guess and the generated number is 5 or smaller, tell user that its close enough, and ask if user wants to continue guessing, but the condition wasn't fulfilled and yet still runs, can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(!(play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")))
        {


            if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
                System.exit(1);
            }

            else{
                if((play.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))){
                    invalid();
                    guess=scan.nextInt();
 ....
```

That isn't right, `if((play.equalsIgnoreCase("y")))` can never be true, since the loop it is in, explicitely cannot be entered if it is true. That's where your problem is, it will always restart the game because it calls Game() in the else-branch. In short, this is what you do:

```
boolean _true = true;

while(! _true) {

    if(_true) {
        //impossible
    }
    else {
        Game(); //ALWAYS
    }
}
```

Since you tagged your question with homework, I will not give the full correction, but now you know where it goes wrong, you should be able to figure out what you need to change in order to advance :)

Comment: there was another problem, before the while condition, there was a line that did not function, the String play = scan.nextLine(); command did not function at all, for unknown reasons i have yet to found out, and is driving me crazy...

Answer (score -1):

You mixed *or* and *and* (Note: The condition you used `(difference<=5||difference>=-5)` is always `true`.). You may use any of the following

```
if (difference<=5 && difference>=-5) { ... }    # difference is 5 or less
```

or

```
if (difference<=-5 || difference>=5) { ... }    # difference is 5 or more
```

Better readable if you use [`Math.abs(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) instead:

```
if (Math.abs(difference)<=5) { ... }    # difference is 5 or less
```

and

```
if (Math.abs(difference)>=5) { ... }    # difference is 5 or more
```

resp.

Comment: Thank you! it look so much clearer when someone explains it to me haha xD

Answer (score -1):

`if(difference<=5||difference>=-5)` This says if the difference is less than 5 or greater than -5. All numbers are less than 5 or greater than -5, so this is **always** true.

I'm assuming what you want is something like `if(Math.abs(difference)<=5)`. This will tell you if the absolute value of your difference variable is less than or equal to 5.

Comment: That won't fix it, just a replacement for a small part of code that does the same...

Comment: Sure about that? His code is true for all numbers, my code is not. Or am I just losing it? :)

Comment: nope, that statement should work (unless **I** am losing it ;)), but you **should** make it `&&` instead of `||`. But what Jon7 suggested is better for that particular if-statement.

Comment: it does simplify the amount of code on one line so i would say it was a good suggestion thanks!

Comment: @user1343502 I'm sorry but your code just doesn't make much sense at all I'm afraid. Why do you get a homework task like this, if your knowledge of programming seems to be so low? Much of the structure is not logical at all. Ask your teacher for help...